# I invoke setVisible on java swing and nothing happens

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to create navigation between frames and setVisible does nothing. I want to close the main window after moving to the next. I have been using windows builder on eclipse and the other .java also extends to JFrame

```
public class LoginF extends JFrame{

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                LoginF window = new LoginF();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public LoginF() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 536, 421);
    setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);        

    JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
```

Nothing happens here

```
    JButton btnRegister = new JButton("Register");
            btnRegister.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Registration nw = new Registration();
                    nw.regScreen();
                    LoginF.this.setVisible(false);


            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You apparently should exclude this when you call LoginF.this.setVisible(false);

Comment: And again , it’s unclear why do you call window.frame.setVisible is your LoginF doesn’t have any components? What you extend JFrame for?

Comment: Why do you have a JFrame field when your class is already extending JFrame?

Comment: Your buttons are not added to any frame, so they are invisible.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

- Your class `LoginF` extends `JFrame` so `this` is your frame. You don't need to create another one.
- You don't use a `GridBagLayout` like this.
- Your buttons are not added to any frame.

I would recommend you to read a book or two.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to set main frame invisible then new frame visible like:

```
Registration nw = new Registration();
LoginF.this.setVisible(false);  
nw.regScreen();
```

This ensures that the first main (GUI) loop is terminated before showing new frame.
Also what is `LoginF.this.setVisible(false)` ? isn't `LoginF.setVisible(false)` enough? because  `LoginF` already extends `JFrame`.
Also make sure JButton is added on somewhere as @Maurice Perry commented.